# git create local branch for a forked upstream tag

Tags: git, branch, fork

I've been trying to find a way to create a local branch that starts from a tag on an upstream repo I've forked and haven't found anything that helps.

I have the upstream master on a master branch locally but I'm not sure what I need to do to branch the upstream tag.

I've tried:

```
git branch upstream/master tagname
git branch master tagname
git branch upstream tagname
```

and none of those worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the tag is fetched (your `master` reflects `upstream/master`)

```
git checkout -b aNewBranch aTagName
```

You need to make sure you [have fetched the tags first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204190/does-git-fetch-tags-include-git-fetch).
That means `git fetch upstream` *and then* `git fetch upstream --tags`

If you want to [fetch only one tag](http://aTagName) (instead of *all* tags from upstream):

```
git fetch upstream refs/tags/aTagName:refs/tags/aTagName
```

Note: with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), that would use the **[new command `git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)**:

```
git switch -c aNewBranch aTagName
```

Comment: I have fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'upstream' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'release.5.1.0' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: @Woody what is your git version? And what is your current branch (git status)?

Comment: @Woody which can not be resolved as commit, you don't seem to havefethced the tags, then (also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987503/6309)

Comment: git fetch upstream --tags resolve the issues, but it fetch all the tags which is bit overkill

Comment: @Woody I agree. Still, my answer did mention the fact you have to fetch the tags first.