# Can git submodule update be made to fetch tags in submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-tag

I have a git repository which uses a submodule which I'd like to point at an annotated tag, but when I do `git submodule update` new tags don't get fetched. I can get new tags in the submodule by cd-ing into the submodule and doing a `git fetch --tags` there, but I'd really like to do all of this from the outside as it's scripted.

I can't find anything in the git documentation suggesting a way to get `git submodule update` to include tags (my git version is 1.7.3.5).

Obviously there is another possibility - to point the submodule at the commit which the tag points to rather than the tag itself, but this doesn't seem as neat.

Is there a way of getting `git submodule update` to include tags?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git submodule` is implemented as a shell script, so it's easy to see what it's doing — it  might be at `/usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule` if you're using a packaged version.  Essentially it just runs `git-fetch` in the submodule if it the object name (SHA1sum) stored in the main project's tree doesn't match the version checked out in the submodule, as [Koraktor points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500741/can-git-submodule-update-be-made-to-fetch-tags-in-submodules/7504682#7504682).

The [documentation for `git fetch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.4.5/git-fetch.html) (or `man git-fetch` while kernel.org is down) says that it should fetch every tag that points to a downloaded object, and the downloaded objects will include every commit that's an ancestor of every branch that's fetched.  That means it's surprising to me that you don't get all the relevant tags on a `git submodule update`.

If it's the case that what you really want is for your script is to try to set a new submodule version and commit that result, I don't think that `git submodule update` is the tool that you want - that's just for making sure that your submodules are at the right version based on what's currently in the main project's commit.  Instead you should just do something like:

```
( cd my-submodule && \
      git fetch && \
      git fetch --tags && \
      git checkout my-tag )
git add my-submodule
git commit -m 'Update the submodule to the "my-tag" version' my-submodule
```

(I added an extra `git fetch --tags` [just in case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204190/does-git-fetch-tags-include-git-fetch) your tag isn't one that points to a downloaded commit.)

> Obviously there is another possibility - to point the submodule at the commit which the tag points to rather than the tag itself, but this doesn't seem as neat.

Well, the only thing that's stored in the main project's tree for the submodule is just the hash of the commit object, so even if there were a command that said "set my submodule to the tag `my-tag` in that submodule", it would end up just storing the hash corresponding to that tag anyway...

Comment: Thanks for all your help - it looks like my problem is that the commit I wanted is not in the history of any branch. Do you think there's a good reason why `git submodule update` only does a `git fetch` and not a `git fetch --tags`? Adding `git fetch --tags` there would sort this problem for anyone who comes across it in the future. When kernel.org is back up I'll find somewhere to report this.

Comment: @DuncanParkes starting git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014), `git fetch --tags` will be enough (no need to add `git fetch`): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309

Answer (score 25):

Late answer here, but I'm surprised that no one mentioned `git submodule foreach`. This is basically the way I solved the exact problem you encountered:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git fetch --tags'
git submodule update --recursive
```

`--recursive` flag is there to recurse into child submodules.

Answer (score 6):

`git submodule update` doesn't fetch anything if your submodules are up-to-date. So this might be a misapprehension.

`git submodule update` will bring the working directory contents of the submodules in your repository to the defined state (i.e. check out the submodule commit that has been defined in your repository).

A better way would be to `cd` into your submodule (which is a Git repository itself) and simply run `git fetch --tags` and then `git checkout some-tag`. After that the submodule has been updated in your working directory to `some-tag` and you can stage it for committing.

Comment: You're right, I did have that misapprehension, but it wasn't my main problem, which is that having set the submodule to point at a tag commit, when I check out somewhere else and do git submodule update, it complains it can't find the commit. I've settled on pointing at the parent of the tag commit.

Answer (score 0):

you can script it so that you do a `(cd path-to-submod && git fetch)`

wrapping the commands in brackets puts the environment in a subshell, meaning, you don't have to CD back out to where you were.

Hope this helps