# How to init a submodule in a tag while keeping the depth at 1

Tags: git, git-submodules

For a normal git repo you can do:

```
git clone --branch 4.1.1 https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git . --depth 1
```

Which will give a WP repo at tag *4.1.1*

For a submodule I did get the below but I can't figure out how to do it for just one tag.

```
git submodule add --depth 1  https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git wp
```

How do I checkout a submodule to *1 tag* at *1 depth*?

I don't mind doing a few more commands afterwards but if possible in one command even better.

**TLDR:**
I want a submodule at a tag. Which .git(/module) folder is as small as possible.

Comment: I suspect with http://stackoverflow.com/a/17693008/6309, but I am still looking for the right command.

Comment: This is a great question and exactly what I have been trying to do myself. It was frustrating having such a huge .git dir just to track one branch. Thanks OP and @VonC for your answer. Probably a question in itself, but if you then want to checkout a new branch, will this clean up the old tag?

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove if the tag is already imported, it will still be there, referencing its own commit: creating a new branch won't change that.

Comment: No tag as yet as I've not done an init on the submodule. I presume you have to git add the submodule first before doing the fetch & checkout as you explain in your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering a submodule might not comes with its tags, you might be tempted to do first (as suggested in "[Can git submodule update be made to fetch tags in submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12284659/6309)"):

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git fetch --tags'
```

But as I explained in "[Does “`git fetch --tags`” include “`git fetch`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)", that would *not* fetch *just* the tags, but also *all* the associated commits (since git 1.9.0, February 2014)

Instead, you can go in the submodule, and fetch that tag content with a depth of 1:

```
git fetch --depth=1 origin refs/tags/<tag>:refs/tags/<tag>
git checkout <tag>
```

Comment: This doesn't work the `git fetch --tags` will fetch everything and then the .git folder is still bigger then 100 mb. Even after the specific checkout it's still big

Comment: @janw yes, I just saw my old answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309! Can you try and test if you can fetch one tag at depth 1? `git fetch --depth=1 origin 'refs/tags/<aTag>:refs/tags/<aTag>'`?

Comment: YES yes that's it. If you could update your answer to include that I'll award the bounty

Comment: `You may award your bounty in 19 hours.` I'll probably forget it on saterday. Got a reminder set for monday

Comment: @janw darn it: tomorrow would have been nice: it is usually very hard to come up with votes on a saturday ;)

Comment: I'll try, no promises (A)