# add remote + swap name with origin, gives error: "git fetch origin; git merge" works, != "git pull" has error -why/how?

Tags: git

I've searched high and low to understand this, and I feel it is just slipping through my fingers. There are similar, but not identical, QnAs here.

The problem:

```
$ git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

Whereas `git fetch` gives nothing, followed by `git merge origin` which says `Already up-to-date.`, which is what I expected had `git pull` worked 'properly'.

```
$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "official"]
    url = git://github.com/freenet/wininstaller-official.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/official/*
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://github.com/freenet/wininstaller-staging.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    tagopt = --tags
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "t"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
1a30b106723624321366f40a078c9ca4c28394ec

$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
1a30b106723624321366f40a078c9ca4c28394ec
```

Why does git pull give error, whilst git fetch/merge produce the expected output?

Background:
I cloned a git repo, freenet/wininstaller-official.git, then saw wininstaller-staging.git and thought "there's likely some not insubstantial overlap there, I ought to add 'staging' as a remote to the first repo". Yeah, now we're cooking with git! This will be so efficient.

Then I thought "staging might be better to track, let's call that origin, and have my local master track new origin/master". Wow! Uber-elte am I!

So I rename remotes as above, delete local master, checkout new master tracking new origin/master.

And `git fetch; git merge` seems to prove it works right!

But alas, `git pull` errors out. Woe is me. Not so uber-elite after all :(

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error from `git pull` is complaining that it can't find the branch that you've told it to merge from.  I suspect that this is because you have `tagopts = --tags` configured for `origin`, and with that option, `git fetch` [doesn't fetch branch heads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204190/does-git-fetch-tags-include-git-fetch).  Try removing that line, and running `git pull` again.

To explain the `pull` / `fetch-and-merge` difference: when you manually run `git fetch`, it doesn't get the `--tags` options, so it does fetch the branch heads.  So, after that point, `origin/master` exists and can be merged from.

---

One other note might be worth adding: it's more normal to use `git merge origin/<branch-name>`, which is more explicit than `git merge origin`.  In that more unusual case, git is interpreting `origin` as the branch `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` - i.e. the current branch (or commit) in the remote repository `origin` the last time you fetched from there.  It's probably better to stick with `git merge origin/<branch-name>` to avoid confusion.