# git tag -l not displaying the most recent releases

Tags: git, release-management

When I go to deploy my django installation, I get the following error:

```
local: git tag -l release/beta* | tail -1
run: git checkout release/beta-20120221-150831 
out: error: pathspec 'release/beta-20120221-150831' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

The tag exists on my local box, but it doesn't on my staging server.  Why?  It sends the most recent release "release/beta-20120221-150831".

Comment: Did you push the tag to your remote repo? If you never pushed it, the staging server can't see it.

Comment: Yes, I can view it as a tagged release on github,  the staging server can't see it.

Comment: Maybe you haven't actually pulled the tag down to the staging server?

Comment: I can't pull it down, because it can't see the release.  I've done git pull origin <branch>.  Nothing.

Comment: You're trying to check out a tag, not a branch. Try `git fetch --tags origin`

Answer (score 8):

Note: as explained in "[Does “`git fetch --tags`” include “`git fetch`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)", starting git 1.9, one command will be enough to fetch both news commits and tags:

```
git fetch --tags origin
```

(Before 1.9, you had to do `git fetch` + `git fetch --tags`)