# How can you configure git to automatically fetch the tags on every pull?

Tags: git

This may or may not be a very dumb idea, but how can you configure a git repository such that any pull that is done automatically fetches the tags from the other repository as well?

According to [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), it looks like you can do this on a per remote reposistory basis:

> remote.<name>.tagopt
>   Setting this value to --no-tags disables
>   automatic tag following when fetching from remote <name>. Setting it
>   to --tags will fetch every tag from remote <name>, even if they are
>   not reachable from remote branch heads. Passing these flags directly
>   to git-fetch(1) can override this setting. See options --tags and
>   --no-tags of git-fetch(1).

Is there way to make `--tags` the default flag to fetch for every fetch?

Answer (score 8):

Fetching tags has a different effect than fetching commits ([`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)), as explained in "[Does “git fetch --tags” include “git fetch”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208223/6309)".

The latter will update branch heads, and will actually fetch tags reachable from those updated branches.
The former will fetch all tags, but won't update the branch heads.

So if your tags are reacheable from the branches you are fetching, you don't have to include `--tags` by default.

Considering the large history of some repos (including the [linux one](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=summary)), always wanting to fetch *all* tags might lead to tag list cluttering (a list of tag pollutted by hundreds of not-needed tags).

---

Note that starting git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014), `git fetch --tags` will fetch everything (like `git fetch`), plus the tags. See "[Does “`git fetch --tags`” include “`git fetch`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)".

> Request that all tags be fetched from the remote **in addition to whatever else is being fetched**.

So you can try the [`remote.<name>.tagOpt`  config option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-remoteltnamegttagOpt):

```
git config (--global) remote.<name>.tagOpt --tags
```

> Setting it to `--tags` will fetch every tag from remote `<name>`, even if they are not reachable from remote branch heads.

Comment: Fetching tags is not the default, so clearly Linus thinks it's a bad idea.  However, my group is used to BitKeeper and they frequently forget to fetch tags when they _should_ (i.e. release tags).  You can delete tags in the event that useless tag volume become ridiculous.

Comment: @RossRogers But if they are fetching the release branches, they would get the tags also.

Comment: The default behavior is to fetch from our git trunk (yes, we have a trunk, though people can pull and push from each other).  This trunk is wrapper'd in an internal tool similar to [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) that only integrates the edits after passing a bunch of tests.

Anyways, they normally _don't_ pull from internal "releases" against which more regressions are run.  They normally pull from the tip of the trunk because it is very well guarded by regressions.  We want them to always grab the tags with one command, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: The original answer says, "no; fetching tags is different". Then there's an update: "fetching tags is no longer different". This update reinstates the question: "how do I get git to fetch tags every time?".

Comment: @LimitedAtonement with `git fetch --tags`. "git fetch --tags will fetch everything (like git fetch), plus the tags. " does *not* mean "fetching tags is no longer different".

Comment: @VonC  Thank you for the response. My mistake; I didn't fully quote the original question: "configure git to **automatically** fetch the tags..."

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Right. I have edited the answer to include the config settings that would make fetch tags automatic.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the update. The OP mentioned that in his question suggesting that it wasn't sufficient. Nonetheless, I think this is still the best we have for now.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Yes, hopefully, this works better now (2018, Git 2.16.x) than in 2012.

Answer (score 7):

Just add this to the config of your remote:

```
fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Comment: any option to do this in global? not just for specify repository.

Comment: Is that in addition to the line that I have now or instead of it? I currently have `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: @isapir It's in addition. One fetches the branches, the other the tags.

Comment: Won't this cause `git push` to also push the local tags?

Answer (score 3):

You can set it with `git config` [1]:

```
git config remote.origin.tagopt --tags
```

To set it globally just add the `--global` switch:

```
git config --global remote.origin.tagopt --tags
```

[1] https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegttagOpt