# Cloning a repo without tags?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-tag

I want to create bare git project without tags using clone.But through Google came to know that there is no option like "`--no-tags`".

Is there any way to clone without tags like below?

```
$ git clone {path}/test.git --no-tags --mirror
```

Any help will be appreciated!! :)

Comment: git clone --mirror -c remote.origin.tagopt=--no-tags .../test.git

Comment: With Git 2.13.x/Git 2.14 (Q2 2017), all you will need is `git clone --no-tags --mirror yourrepo`. The `--no-tags` option is now real! See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44011502/6309)

Comment: And for configuring an existing remote, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12542314/1959808

Answer (score 15):

With Git 2.13.x/2.14 (Q2 2017), this will be possible (ie: clone without tags)

See [commit 1524ccd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1524ccdc1873029e4eafa5bffae2aa66d02369d8), [commit 0dab246](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dab2468ee5bbfaa854a22eb17c70647fc8b6b83), [commit 28d67d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28d67d9a262c7600f5c17bb8e2072fd224260ade) (26 Apr 2017) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a1fdc85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1fdc85f419022df5f2246b0444db4679e528e63), 16 May 2017)</sup>

> ### `clone`: add a `--no-tags` option to clone without tags
>
> Add a `--no-tags` option to clone without fetching any tags.
>
> Without this change there's no easy way to clone a repository without
>   also fetching its tags.
>
> When supplying `--single-branch` the primary remote branch will be cloned, but in addition tags will be followed & retrieved.
>   Now `--no-tags` can be added `--single-branch` to clone a repository without
>   tags, and which only tracks a single upstream branch.
>
> This option works without `--single-branch` as well, and will do a
>   normal clone but not fetch any tags.
>
> Many git commands pay some fixed overhead as a function of the number of references. E.g. creating ~40k tags in `linux.git` will cause a command like `git log -1 >/dev/null` to run in over a second instead of in a matter of milliseconds, in addition numerous other things will slow down, e.g. "`git log <TAB>`" with the bash completion will slowly show ~40k references instead of 1.
>
> The user might want to avoid all of that overhead to simply use a repository like that to browse the "master" branch, or **something like a CI tool might want to keep that one branch up-to-date without caring about any other references**.
>
> Without this change the only way of accomplishing this was either by
>   manually tweaking the config in a fresh repository:
>
> ```
> git init git &&
>  cat >git/.git/config <<EOF &&
>  [remote "origin"]
>      url = git@github.com:git/git.git
>      tagOpt = --no-tags
>      fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
>  [branch "master"]
>      remote = origin
>      merge = refs/heads/master
>  EOF
>  cd git &&
>  git pull
> ```
>
> Which requires hardcoding the "`master`" name, which may not be the main
>   `--single-branch` would have retrieved, or alternatively by setting
>   `tagOpt=--no-tags` right after cloning & deleting any existing tags:
>
> ```
> git clone --single-branch git@github.com:git/git.git &&
>  cd git &&
>  git config remote.origin.tagOpt --no-tags &&
>  git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
> ```
>
> Which of course was also subtly buggy if `--branch` was pointed at a
>   tag, leaving the user in a detached head:
>
> ```
> git clone --single-branch --branch v2.12.0 git@github.com:git/git.git &&
>  cd git &&
>  git config remote.origin.tagOpt --no-tags &&
>  git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
> ```
>
> Now all this complexity becomes the much simpler:
>
> ```
> git clone --single-branch --no-tags git@github.com:git/git.git
> ```
>
> Or in the case of cloning a single tag "branch":
>
> ```
> git clone --single-branch --branch v2.12.0 --no-tags git@github.com:git/git.git
> ```

Comment: I have `git version 2.13.0` and so I don't have `--no-tags`, but it seems that just using `--single-branch` is enough to avoid downloading the tags. Am I missing something?

Comment: @janos 2.13.*0*? Man, I don't even remember what life was like at 2.13.0. I was young back then. We are at 2.13.3 now. And https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dab2468ee5bbfaa854a22eb17c70647fc8b6b83 has been marked for the upcoming 2.14 (31st of July, in less than 2 weeks): https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=jfgbl2mrlipp4pb6ieih0qr3so@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/Los_Angeles

Comment: @janos I just tested (with 2.13.3) `git clone --single-branch https://github.com/git/git`, and all the tags accessible from `master` are there in the local clone (`git tag --sort=v:refname`). A tag like `junio-gpg-pub` would not be present, because not on the `master` branch.

Comment: The tags I didn't get were on branches that were not merged to master, so that explains, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Release notes of git/2.14.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.14.0.txt#L35), now there would be a support to exclude tags while cloning a repository.

> ```
> "git clone" learned the "--no-tags" option not to fetch all tags   
> initially, and also set up the tagopt not to follow any tags in   
> subsequent fetches.
> ```

Use the following command in future :-

```
git clone <repositoryUrl> --no-tags
```

Answer (score 1):

"Mirror" implies "tags": you can't have the former without the latter.

Fundamentally, `--mirror` means:

- a bare clone, with
- the ref-spec for fetch reading `refs/*:refs/*`

Since tags live in `refs/tags/`, the second bullet item above means that tags get copied.

To avoid copying tags, you will need a different set of refspecs.  Pick the one(s) that you wish to have copied (perhaps `refs/heads/*` and `refs/notes/*` for instance) and list those explicitly in your bare clone.  (You can start by making a full `--mirror` clone, then editing the config file and removing any unwanted already-copied refs.)

You probably also want to set `remote.name.tagopt` to `--no-tags` to disable automatic "matching tag" fetches.