# Fetching all tags from a remote with git pull

Tags: git

I currently have a git remote setup like the following:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = <redacted>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

When I issue `git pull` on branch master, all remote heads are fetched into remotes/upstream, then remotes/upstream/master is merged into master. Any tags that can be reached are also fetched at the same time, which is very convenient.

I'd like `git pull` to additionally fetch *all* tags from the remote, not just those that are directly reachable from the heads. I originally tried seting `tagopt == --tags`, but found this caused only tags to be fetch and thus broke everything. (Junio even says that's a [horrendous misconfiguation](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/unclear-documentation-of-git-fetch-tags-option-and-tagopt-config-tp7572964p7573006.html)).

Is there a way to make `git pull` fetch all remote tags by default, in addition to the remote heads?

Comment: A reminder to myself: Make sure you actually pushed the tag first (does not work automatically):

   `git push origin <tag_name>`

Comment: Using `tagopt` solution is no longer a misconfiguration; [as of 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181) this will fetch all tags *in addition* to whatever is normally fetched.

Comment: The original question didn't specify "by default", it was more general. And many answer specified command lines, including the one that is the most voted. Changing the title left those answers unrelated. Therefore I have restored the original title that was previously changed.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by adding a refspec for tags to your local config. Concretely:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = <redacted>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Comment: Aha, I never realized you could have multiple fetch lines, I presumed the last one would just override. That's very nice and explicit.

Comment: Beware using this with git 2.21, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352404/git-clone-fails-with-fatal-multiple-updates-for-ref-refs-tags-v1-0-0-not-all

Comment: Is there any way to add the second refspect via `git <something>` command instead of editing the local config directly? That way it would be much easier to instruct junior devs what to do.

Answer (score 388):

A simple `git fetch --tags` worked for me.

Comment: @Fizzix Perhaps the title should be altered to include "by default". This post answered my question.

Comment: This did not work for me. I can see the tags with `git ls-remote`.

Comment: This may not answer the exact question, but it does answer the question in the title and that's how I found it through the web search.

Comment: *WARNING:* This fetches all origin branches as well as tags. I came her looking to *ONLY* fetch tags and not otherwise change the state of my local repository.

Comment: @MattKneiser the original question didn't specify "by default", it was more general. And many answer specified command lines, including this one that is the most voted. Changing the title left those answers unrelated.

Answer (score 81):

The `--force` option is useful for refreshing the local tags. Mainly if you have floating tags:

```
git fetch --tags --force
```

The git pull option has also the `--force` options, and the description is the same:

> When git fetch is used with <rbranch>:<lbranch> refspec, it refuses to
>   update the local branch <lbranch> unless the remote branch <rbranch>
>   it fetches is a descendant of <lbranch>. This option overrides that
>   check.

but, according to the doc of `--no-tags`:

> By default, tags that point at objects that are downloaded from the
>   remote repository are fetched and stored locally.

If that default statement is not a restriction, then you can also try

```
git pull --force
```

Comment: `git pull --force` doesn't include `git fetch --tags --force`

Answer (score 25):

For me the following seemed to work.

```
git pull --tags
```

Comment: Fetching tags only, you probably meant:
`  git fetch --tags`

Comment: There is already an answer with `git fetch --tags`. I wanted to give an alternative answer. pull = fetch + merge. So fetch also happens.

Answer (score 18):

None of the answers worked for me when *remote tags were deleted* - their local equivalents would still exists in the fetching/pulling repo.

I found this combination of `git fetch` attributes the only way to pick up on deleted tags:

```
git fetch --tags --prune --prune-tags
```

Alternatively, this can be applied to the local (or global) git configuration:

```
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = [gitlab url]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    tagopt = --tags
    prune = true
    pruneTags = true
...
```

Nice side effect: This will also work for `git pull` (I was unable to achieve this via command line attributes).

Commands to add configuration:

```
git config (--global) remote.origin.tagopt --tags
git config (--global) remote.origin.prune true
git config (--global) remote.origin.pruneTags true
```

Comment: Yes, I realize this. Also being the opposite of the request of the question. But regardless you may want to explain that in bold at the top of your answer.

Answer (score 15):

It's simple. Do a

```
git fetch --all
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this with magit on kernel.org

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = <redacted>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
    tagOpt = --tags
```