# Git tags don't show up as GitHub releases

Tags: git, github

So... I have a Git repository on my desktop computer that is linked to a GitHub repository. When I do:

```
git tag -a -F C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Temp\git-tag-message-4665532737910125701.txt v0.1 63f5
```

the tag doesn't show up as a release on the GitHub website. (Note: An IDE handles all of the Git->GitHub stuff for me) Do I have to "push" something after  I make a tag?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Do I have to "push" something after I make a tag?

Yes:

```
git push --tags
```

(since [GitHub releases](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases) are based on git tags)

Comment: Thanks that helped... Apparently my IDE doesn't support that so I had to put it into the console, but it worked :)

Comment: And I just found out you can also pull the tags from GitHub to have them locally.

Comment: @stragu Yes, and if you want, you can make a simple `git pull` to [fetch all remote tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68539133/6309) (in addition of the commits).