# Github release/tag not showing up locally?

Tags: git, github

I pushed some code to a remote repository and then created a first release on GitHub, giving it the title *'v0.0.1'*. GitHub now shows that I now have one release and also shows that in 'tags' I have a tag *'v0.0.1'*.

I then executed `git pull origin master` to update the local repo and it returned `'Already up-to-date.'` Now if I enter `git tag` nothing happens.

So why isn't this tag showing up locally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching all tags from a remote with git pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678072/fetching-all-tags-from-a-remote-with-git-pull)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `git pull origin master` runs `git fetch origin master` followed, in effect, by `git merge origin/master`.  The `git fetch` step provides too many constraints on `git fetch`, inhibiting it from obtaining your tag.  If you yourself run `git fetch origin` or even just `git fetch`, you will obtain the tag.

#### Background

Note that the first command that `git pull` runs—`git fetch origin master`—uses two separate arguments, `origin` and `master`, and the second does not; instead, it has this odd slash: `git merge origin/master`.  This is all due to history: `git pull` was there first, back in 2005 or so, and it turns out to do too much and to do it not so well; so a separate, more-useful `git fetch` was provided as a standard user-facing command.  Around this time, the whole concept of "remotes" was invented.  The name `origin` is itself one of these remotes.

Remotes come with *remote-tracking branches*, and `origin/master`, with the slash in it, is one of these remote-tracking branches.  Despite the word "remote" here, a "remote-tracking branch" is in fact just another name in your own (local) repository: it's your Git's way of remembering for you what *your* Git saw on the other (origin) Git, the last time your Git talked to theirs.

In the beginning (2005-ish again), you had to run `git pull <url> <branch>`, which is why the two are separate.  There were no remotes, and no remote-tracking branches, so you had to have your Git call up their Git by URL, obtain their branch, and then immediately merge the result into your branch.  So you named the URL by which to call up their Git over the Internet-phone, and then named *their* branch.

You can now run `git fetch` with *no arguments at all*, which will call up `origin` (your Git uses your name `origin` to save the URL) on the Internet-phone and obtain everything, and then *remember it all for you*, using tags and remote-tracking branches.  After that, `git merge` *with no arguments at all* will generally do the right thing: if you're on `master` it will merge `origin/master`, which is what your Git remembers from their Git.  But `git pull` lives on, in part because after `git fetch`, you usually *want* to do at least one more Git command, and `git pull` does `git fetch` and then one more Git command—and it still uses that same old syntax: a URL (but now you can use a "remote" name), followed by the name of the branch *as seen on the Git at that URL*.

My advice to those new to Git is: never use `git pull`; your Git life will be happier.  It *seems* convenient, but it has all these traps for the unwary.  For instance, the second command you run should quite often be `git rebase`, not `git merge`.  The way to *find out* which command to use is to run `git fetch` and then `git log`—but `git pull` requires that you decide *in advance* whether to rebase or merge, *before* you look to see which would be better.

Comment: Excellent answer thanks! I now have the tag after using git fetch. I entered 'git merge' then as you suggested but it says 'No remote for the current branch.' I only have one branch and that is master. Should I enter something else after 'git merge' to specify the remote?

Comment: Ah, in that case you probably want to set `origin/master` as what Git calls the *upstream* for branch `master` (this term is a little ambiguous, several different things are sometimes called "upstream"). You can use `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` to set the upstream of `master` to `origin/master`. After that, Git associates `master` with `origin/master` for `git merge` and `git rebase` with no additional arguments. (There are some slightly shorter commands to do the same, but this is the most general form.)

Comment: You can set any remote-tracking branch as the upstream for any branch, but you get just one such setting per branch. You can also "unset" the upstream for a branch if you just want to remove the linkage between them. It's a little odd to *need* to set the upstream, as the default `git clone` action sets the upstream for `master` to `origin/master` automatically. (Perhaps you did not go through the default process?)