# Find more recent commit pointed a tag in all branch

Tags: git, command-line, tags

I work on a PHP script who sends a Slack message when a one of our servers isn't up to date.
Currently we use git tag for trigger build and publication.

So I search a git command to display most recent commit pointed a tag on any branch (for example more recent commit pointed on **production-server-1** or **demo-server-2** tag.

I tried following commands :

```
git --no-pager log -n 1 --format=%ai production-server-1

git rev-list  -n 1 production-server-1 | xargs git show
```

But outputed information doesn't match with our git repository information.

Is it possible to do this with a command line ?

Thanks

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you are looking for. A Git *tag name* (`v1.2` or `demo-server-2` or whatever) contains a Git hash ID, which is normally either the ID of a commit (a "lightweight tag"), or the ID of an annotated-tag object (an "annotated tag"). In the latter case, the annotated tag object then points to a commit. Using `git rev-parse <tag-name>^{commit}` will find the hash ID of the commit.

Comment: I will try to explain it differently. For example I work on a new feature. I create a branch **feature/add-dropodwn**. Now to publish it on our demo server, I tag a commit with  **demo-server** tag and I push. Now how can I retrieve this commir ID ? Is it clearer ?

Comment: A *branch name* is a moveable pointer to a commit: to resolve a branch name to its current commit ID, `git rev-parse <branch-name>` or `git rev-parse refs/heads/<branch-name>` will do the job. A tag name, as I noted above, is kind of the same thing except that it may point to an annotated tag (and it's not *supposed* to change once established), so `git rev-parse <tag-name>` may get you the annotated tag object and you need the `^{commit}` suffix to force resolution to the commit object. Is `git rev-parse <tag-name>^{commit}` not working for you? If not, do you have an example?

Comment: Currently when I run `git rev-parse demo-server-1 | xargs git show`, it displays a commit pushed in Febrary but in bitbucket interface, last commit with demo-server-1 tag was pushed yesterday. You said a tag is not supposed to changed, but currently we move tags across branch, mays it's a problem.

Comment: Yes: moving a tag is a bad idea; different consumers will act differently, because they may assume, or even guarantee, that the tag does not move (to guarantee that the tag does not move, a Git client can simply avoid replacing any existing tags with any updated versions).

Comment: Thanks for details, I will speak about it with my team.So currently, without change our flow, do you know a command to find last commit pointed ?

Comment: The problem is that you now have inconsistent tags. Repository A claims that tag `demo-server-1` is the commit with hash ID 1234567; Repository B claims that tag `demo-server-1` is the commit with hash ID 9876543. Perhaps there is a Repository C that makes a third claim. Which one should I believe, and why? Answer that, and you have your answer to "how to find the commit".

Comment: Tags arn't in other repositories, but accross branchies. I note move tag is a bad idea, but when we move a tag from a branch A to  branch B for example, we remove it from A and add it to B.

Comment: Tags *are* in other repositories. Tags usually appear in *every* repository. That's one of the key items that distinguishes them from branches, in Git: branches get *renamed* (so you have both `master` and `origin/master`, which lets you work with both separately) but tags do not. Tags do not live in branches in Git; they reside outside the branch system. (This differs greatly from, e.g., Mercurial.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of two git commands :

```
git show -s --format=%ci $(git rev-list -n 1 production-server-1)
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I also used a command for fetch all tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678072/fetching-all-tags-from-a-remote-with-git-pull . Some tags was just outdated