# git does't retrieve remote tags with pull but it does with fetch

Tags: git, git-pull, git-tag, git-fetch

I'm using a git repository with many remote tags.

In another PC, if I use this command:

```
git pull origin develop
```

I don't have new remote tags created by another station, but if I use following command:

```
git fetch origin
```

I download also tags. Tags are created in `develop` branch, and, as far as I know, `git pull` is a shortcut for `git fetch` and `git merge`.

If I clone the repository in a new folder I can retrieve all tags instead.

So why I can't download new tags from remote repository and how can I fix it?

I'm using git 2.21 on windows 10 64 bit, with git bash.

Comment: And if you do `git fetch origin develop:develop` does it retrieve tags? (I think no)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching all tags from a remote with git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678072/fetching-all-tags-from-a-remote-with-git-pull)

Comment: `git pull --tags` does that work?