# git pull - will it fetch tags on remote by default?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-tag

I know `git fetch --tags` will fetch all tags from remote to local.

I am not sure will `git pull` get tags from remote by default, so will it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should, since [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) does a [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) and a [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

But it will do so only from git 1.9.0+, as I mentioned in "[Does “`git fetch --tags`” include “`git fetch`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)".

Answer (score 6):

A git pull will by default only fetch tags that are reachable by the objects that are fetched.

From the [git pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) documentation

> **--no-tags**
>
> By default, tags that point at objects that are downloaded from the remote repository are fetched and stored locally. This option disables this automatic tag following. The default behavior for a remote may be specified with the remote.<name>.tagopt setting. See [git-config[1]](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

So you should also take a look at the `tagopt` config to see what git does for your repository.

> **remote.<name>.tagopt**
>
> Setting this value to --no-tags disables automatic tag following when fetching from remote . Setting it to --tags will fetch every tag from remote , even if they are not reachable from remote branch heads. Passing these flags directly to git-fetch[1](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) can override this setting. See options --tags and --no-tags of git-fetch[1](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).