# Git pull doesn't get new tags and new branches but git fetch does

Tags: git

I had trouble trying to get my coworker new created tags when he told me he already pushed them up and they where up in the repo. It wasn't until I used git fetch when I could get the new tag and actually informed me about a new branch created. I knew git pull is basically git fetch & git merge so I was wondering why it wasn't getting the latest changes. Here are the two situations:

```
git pull origin dev
From ******.****.*****/*******
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

git fetch
From ****.****.com:*******/*******
   ae06d29..958f332  master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      task-Q -> origin/task-Q
 * [new tag]         demo_5-21  -> demo_5-21
 * [new tag]         demo_5_27  -> demo_5_27
```

Was I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the synopsis of [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) we see:

> `'git pull' [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]`

When you run `git pull origin dev` you are specifying that you want to pull the refspec `dev` from the remote `origin`. Since you're specifically asking for the `dev` branch, no other branches or tags are pulled.

Instead, try `git pull --all`.

Comment: Actually the `--all` flag fetches _all remotes_ (if you have remotes other than 'origin' then git will fetch each of them).  I added another answer below to explain.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**: 'git pull' is a 'git fetch; git merge'.

**No**: 'git fetch --all' will not fetch all tags by default without '--tags' ... it will [fetch reachable tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716846/git-pull-will-it-fetch-tags-on-remote-by-default), see third part of my answer below.

Likewise: ['git push'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988088/do-git-tags-get-pushed-as-well) does not push tags by default without '--tags'.

Your `git pull origin dev` fetched only the **remote dev branch**.  If you had typed `git pull` or `git pull origin` you would get the new branch ... depending on the configuration.  What is fetched is controlled by three things, you probably took advantage of the last one:

**Command line**: While `git pull --tags` works, it won't necessarily fetch tracking branches ... and git reminds you to use `git fetch --tags`.  This would have fetched your coworker's tags, but not any branches.

```
$ git pull --tags
. . .
Fetching tags only, you probably meant:
    git fetch --tags
```

**Remote/branch fetch configuration**: With bare `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` the remote and branch configuration controls behavior.  These didn't come into play:

```
$ git config remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

$ git config --get-regexp 'branch.master*'
branch.master.remote origin
branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

**Upstream branch/tag history**: According to the second paragraph of the [git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) documentation

> By default, any tag that points into the histories being fetched is
> also fetched; the effect is to fetch tags that point at branches that
> you are interested in.

This means that when your coworker pushed a branch with new tags in its history, **your `git fetch` got the new branch and the new tags.**

Comment: My issue was that I used "git push" which does not push tags by default. "git push --tags" followed by a "git pull" on the other end solved my problem.

Comment: @BrookeWallace good point, I added a note to the answer.  There is an asymmetry between 'git push' without --tags pushing no tags, and 'git fetch' without --tags fetching reachable tags.