# Is there a .gitconfig pull option to always fetch annotated tags?

Tags: git

Git 2.4.1 introduced the `push.followTags` option, which will automatically push your annotated tags.  That is, it makes every `git push...` equivalent to `git push --follow-tags...`, which is exactly what I want.

But I can't figure out how to get the same behavior when pulling.  That is, I would like every

```
git pull
```

to be equivalent to:

```
git pull && git fetch --tags
```

Is there any option that accomplishes this?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure they aren't fetched by default?

Comment: It's strange, I just read that they were after posting this, but I posted this because I did a pull that *didn't* fetch them, and I had to `get fetch --tags` manually afterward.  I wonder if there was something else going on causing the problem...

Comment: Maybe you've explicitly specified references to fetch?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What happened in my case was another dev created some tags, and pushed them, and I pulled his changes, and his tags weren't there.  After a `git fetch --tags`, they were.

Comment: Ok, fwiw, I just tested this again locally on a fresh repo, and got the same results: git pull did not grab the annotated tags by default.  I had to `git fetch --tags`

Comment: Ahh, I usually use `git fetch [<remote>]` which actually fetches data with tags

Comment: maybe use alias? `[alias] fetch = fetch --tags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[Does “`git fetch --tags`” include “`git fetch`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)", since git 1.9+; `git fetch --tag` includes `git fetch` + the tags.
And `git pull --tags` would also include them.

So adding `--tags` is the surest way to get the tags in addition of what `git fetch/pull` is normally getting from the remote.

But by default, tags are not fetched automatically, to avoid polluting the tags namespace of the local repo, especially with the default refspecs `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` which fetches `heads` only.

Comment: So an alias like `git pt` for `git pull --tags` is my best bet?

Comment: @Jonah yes, if you need to pull tags, an alias is recommended.

Comment: Thanks, just one more question about git's default behavior, and the "pollution" you mentioned.  If the tags were pushed to the server, won't they usually be important public info that you want to pull?  Eg, in my case, we're tagging commits that are released to our production server.  Is there a better alternative?

Comment: @Jonah no, typically larges repo like the linux kernel or the git repo itself accumulate a *lot* of tags over times. The users of those repo are not interested in *all* those tags, just the master branch. If they need more, there are options for them to get more from a remote.

Comment: So `git pull --tags` grabs tags from all branches, not just the one you're pulling down?  Whereas `git fetch --tags` will act only on the current branch?  Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @Jonah No, pull or fetch should get back the same tags (*all* the tags: `refs/tags/*`)

Comment: How do people working on git/linux get just the master branch tags?

Comment: @Jonah sorry, I meant all the tags accessible by the commits fetched or pulled.