# How do I sync tags to a forked github repo?

Tags: github

I forked a repository on github and use the "fetch and merge" button on the web page to sync the latest code to my fork. I noticed that the code gets updated but new tags from the master repro don't end up in my fork. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You would need, in command-line, to [fetch tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)

```
git fetch --tags upstream
```

Assuming `upstream` is the remote name referencing the original repository URL.
(If not yet defined: [`git remote add upstream https://github.com/original/repository`](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/configuring-a-remote-repository-for-a-fork)).

Then push tags to your fork

```
git push --tags
```

If you want to [push only the tags from the branch you are pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309):

```
git config --global push.followTags true
```

That way, a simple `git push` is enough.

Comment: It worked, yay!

Comment: @BobbyDore Great! Well done.

Comment: @VonC I don't get how can I execute a command line in github. I mean, I can execute in my local machine where there is a clone of the forked repository, but the upstream of it is not the original repository I forked from, but the forked repository itself, so the command has no effect.

Comment: @Gustavo You need to [add the remote `upstream`](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/configuring-a-remote-repository-for-a-fork): `git remote add upstream https://github.com/original/project`. Then the command will have effect.

Comment: @VonC Doing it isn't the same as cloning the original repository? Won't I lose the ability to push to the upstream? After syncing the tags should I restore the upstream to the forked repo again?

Comment: @Gustavo Usually, you clone your fork, and then add a reference ("upstream") to the original repository. "upstream" differs from "origin" (your default remote, to which you are pushing to).

Comment: I know this is a different question but it's closely tied to this use-case. Although the tags can now be synced, how do you sync the 'Releases' information from a repository that you've forked from?  It seems like it might be Github specific metadata and not something the git command can accomodate.

Comment: @Frak Good question. I don't believe that is feasible. I am not aware a [GitHub release](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/about-releases) can be "sync'ed" with a fork.

Answer (score 5):

For the first one, this also works

```bash
git fetch --tags <remote-url>
```